# MySQL Stored Procedure using Input Variable in With Clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Slowly working through change MSSQL database to MySQL and the final problem is as follows :-

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `user_GetUserInRole`(
        IN $EMail               nvarchar(256),
        IN $RoleName            nvarchar(256),
        INOUT $ReturnStatus bit)
BEGIN

    DECLARE $UserId     char(38);
    DECLARE $RoleId        char(38);
    DECLARE $this_count INT;

    SET $UserId = (SELECT UserId FROM server.`user_Data` WHERE EMail = $EMail);
    SET $RoleId = (SELECT RoleId FROM server.`user_Roles` WHERE RoleName = $RoleName);

    SET $this_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_UsersInRoles WHERE UserId = $UserId AND RoleId = $RoleId);

    IF ($this_count > 0) THEN
        SET $ReturnStatus = 1;
    ELSE
        SET $ReturnStatus = 0;
    END IF;

END
```

Always returns 0, even when I know the count is equal to 1.  I believe that there is an issue with the input variables not being recognized properly by the Where clause in both `Select UserId` and `Select RoleId` statements, but I can't see what I'm doing differently to the various helps I've found.

Any help, as always, is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have since tried running a simple insert command

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO server.`test_table`
    VALUES('test', 'test2');

END
```

And this hasn't worked either.  This leads me to believe that it's actually more of a problem with the PDO call.

```
$command = "EXEC test";
$stpro = $conn->prepare($command);
$returnvalue = $stpro->execute();
```

I know that `$conn` works as straight sql calls in my php definitely work.

**EDIT 2**

So, turns out `EXEC` should have been `CALL`.  This now works with the test.  As soon as I put any parameters into it though it stops working.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so in case anyone else runs into this problem, I finally have the answer.  The problem is that PDO does not allow you to bind parameters to `OUT` variables properly.  As a result you need to run two queries in order for the `CALL` to run properly.  This allows the variable to be read though the `$output` arrange and away you go.

```
    $role = "Admin";
    $command = "CALL user_GetUserInRole ('" . $_SESSION['vaild_user'] . "', '" . $role . "', @returnvalue)";        

    $conn->query($command);

    $output = $conn->query("SELECT @returnvalue")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    if ($output["@returnvalue"] == 1)
    {
        $admin = true;
    }
```

Comment: Gotta love people marking down answers that work without leaving any comments.

Comment: I got your back chris ;)

Answer (score 1):

No need of `$Email`. Make your parameter declaration like

```
IN email nvarchar(256)
```

Change your `select` inside procedure as below

FROM

```
SET $UserId = (SELECT UserId FROM server.`user_Data` WHERE EMail = $EMail);
```

TO

```
SET @UserId := (SELECT UserId FROM server.`user_Data` WHERE EMail = email);
```

with that, your procedure should look like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `user_GetUserInRole`(
        IN email               nvarchar(256),
        IN rolename            nvarchar(256),
        INOUT retstatus bit)
BEGIN

    SET @UserId := (SELECT UserId FROM server.`user_Data` WHERE EMail = email);
    SET @RoleId := (SELECT RoleId FROM server.`user_Roles` 
    WHERE RoleName = rolename);

    SET @this_count := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_UsersInRoles 
    WHERE UserId = @UserId AND RoleId = @RoleId);

    IF (@this_count > 0) THEN
        SET retstatus = 1;
    ELSE
        SET retstatus = 0;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Have just tried this, but it's still returning 0.  Thanks though.

Comment: @ChrisHarland, looks like you have already figured out that the issue is with call from PHP. Sorry, can't help there since that's out of my area. Take a look at Meda's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so at this this where I am at the moment @meda.  Thought I'd post as a separate "answer" to avoid any confusion.

The current Procedure is :-

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `user_GetUserInRole`(
        IN email                nvarchar(256),
        IN rolename             nvarchar(256),
        OUT returnstatus        int)
BEGIN

    SELECT @UserId := UserId FROM server.`user_data` WHERE EMail = email;

    SELECT @RoleId := RoleId FROM server.`user_roles` WHERE RoleName = rolename;

    SELECT @this_count := COUNT(*) FROM server.`user_usersinroles` WHERE UserId = @UserId AND RoleId = @RoleId;

    IF (@this_count > 0) THEN
        SET @returnstatus = 1;
    ELSE
        SET @returnstatus = 0;
    END IF;

END
```

This is launched by the php :-

```
    $command = "CALL user_GetUserInRole (?, ?, ?)";
    $role = "Admin";

    $stpro = $conn->prepare($command);
    $stpro->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['vaild_user']);
    $stpro->bindParam(2, $role);
    $stpro->bindParam(3, $returnvalue, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);

    $success = $stpro->execute();

    if($success)
    {
        $returnvalue = $stpro->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

If I remove the `OUT returnstatus int` from the Procedure and the third parameter from the php it runs perfectly and if I add an Insert command for debug purposes in the procedure I am getting the correct answers from the queries.

However, as soon as the `OUT` is returned to the statement the whole thing falls over and `$success = $stpro->execute();` returns "false" every time.

Answer (score -1):

[**PDOStatement::execute**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)  will return a boolean value based on success or failure of the stored procedure call.

So `$returnvalue` is not really what you think, try this instead:

```
$command = "EXEC test ?";
$param = "123";
$stpro = $conn->prepare($command);
$stpro ->bindParam(1, $param, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$success = $stpro->execute();
if($success){
    $returnvalue = $stpro->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($returnvalue);
}else{
    echo "execute() failed!"; 
}
```

Comment: this works, and I also have it working when passing the two IN variables in the initial example.  However, as soon as I start trying to run the procedure with the INOUT (tried as OUT as well) variable the execute command always returns "false" meaning that it does not successfully run.

Comment: @ChrisHarland I update my answer, you should update your post with the new code that is failing

Comment: Posted as requested @meda.  Thank you.